Automatically setting the parameters based on player's ability
I work on a simple arcade game. The player controls a diver. The diver moves forward at a constant speed. The player can use input controls to move the diver up or down. Along the way, the diver encounters tunnels, and the player must then move the diver down so that the diver goes through the tunnel. The diver consumes oxygen at a constant rate. The player loses if the diver runs out of oxygen. Along the way, there are oxygen bottles, and the player can move the diver up to collect them. The player wins if the diver reaches the end of the path.
As the game should be played by players with widely varying abilities, I would like to automatically determine some of the game parameters, so that the game difficulty would fit the player: the game should be challenging, but not too hard. The following parameters can be changed:

The speed of forward movement, and the speed of up/down movement.
The rate of oxygen consumption, and the amount of oxygen in a bottle.
The height and length of each cave.
The number of caves, and the distance between adjacent caves.

Is there an algorithm for determining these parameters for a specific player, given e.g. 30 seconds of gameplay? Any reference to such an algorithm is welcome.
In particular, can it be done using the new AI system in Unity 6?

All the parameters you mentioned decrease the difficulty. The difference between them is basically the equation: "how much you modify the element" / "how much easier the game became". However, you have to take into account how easy it is to modify each of these elements. In any case, doing an analysis manually (something like knowing what the player is bumping into or if his oxygen level is too low) seems easier to me than learning how to use "Unity's ml-agents", but much less interesting. If your goal is to use an AI, you can start here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents

@BonecoSinforoso By "doing an analysis manually" I can determine a fixed difficulty level. But I want to game to automatically adapt itself to players with different abilities; I am not there to manually set the difficulty level for them.

By manual analysis, I mean that you can create a script that analyzes it. For example: if the player's oxygen level drops below 30%, the oxygen reduction rate will be reduced. If the player is able to constantly catch several oxygen balloons, to the point where the oxygen level remains above 70% for 60 seconds, the oxygen reduction rate will increase.

@BonecoSinforoso OK, but how can I set the exact numbers for this? I want to determine the numbers by some automatic process (algorithm).

To get the numbers automatically, you first need to define some general formula that would solve a level for you. If your cave is X long, what would be the minimum speed, refill rate, refill spawn, amount, etc. The other approach could be to have an AI agent that can play your game perfectly and you randomize the parameter until the agent can win barely and use those as a constant for your levels

There's no standard-issue algorithm for processing a gameplay trace and computing the exact difficulty parameters that will match the player's performance.
I'd be skeptical of training AI to do this, because that usually requires giving the training routine some concrete target — in this case telling it "what does the right level of difficulty look like?" — and that's a hard question to boil down to a formula the training routine can optimize against.
Instead, what we can try doing is make the system dynamically tune itself on the fly in response to the player's current progress. This is the same principle behind using a PID controller to make a robot self-balancing, or a centrifugal governor to regulate the pressure and speed of a steam engine. We introduce a negative feedback loop, where the current state of the system feeds back into the system as input to affect its future rate of change.
Some good examples of this in games:

Dynamic difficulty in Resident Evil 4 that varies enemy spawns, health, aggression, and loot drops based on recent deaths / failed QTEs.
The Left 4 Dead "Director" system that throttles zombie spawning based on a "stress" stat tracked for each player character.
Mario Kart item boxes, varying drop rates based on a player's position in the race.

In the situation you describe, I'd be cautious about changing the player's speed. Core 3Cs should generally stay consistent throughout the game, so players can develop their skills in mastering that control system. Changing how the character controls can feel jarring or inconsistent.
I'd also be cautious of changing core rules like how long a given amount of oxygen lasts, as this can feel like the game cheating by making the countdown timer run faster than it had previously established it would.
You can get away with these things if they're presented as coming from an external hazard: say tangling weeds or opposing currents that slow the player down or make them burn oxygen faster while fighting against. But in open, normal-looking water, I should be able to count on my movement and oxygen depletion rules behaving in a consistent, predictable manner.
Rather than changing the amount of oxygen in a bottle, it would be good to introduce multiple different sizes of bottle, each with a standard quantity inside. Then you can vary the difficulty by spawning more or fewer bottles, or varying the proportion of large vs small bottles, while still keeping a consistent rule that when the player sees a bottle, they can predict how much oxygen it will give them (and whether it will be worthwhile to go collect it).
For the cave parameters, you can use a system that generates the cave one chunk at a time, populating only the portion that's currently visible on screen. That lets you vary the generation parameters as the player progresses, so their performance early in the level can affect how easy or difficult you make the caves late in the level, rather than committing to the entire cave system at level start. Hazards like currents / weeds / hostile creatures / etc. can often be spawned just in time when you need a difficulty spike.
To measure how hard a time the player is having, you can track metrics like:

Their number of deaths in the past [x] levels or [y] minutes

Their current oxygen level

The proportion of time they've been below [x]% oxygen in the past [y] minutes


Similar to the Left 4 Dead example, you can combine several metrics into a derived "stress" stat to estimate how much adversity the player is feeling, maybe something like...
$$ \text{stress} =  \frac {\text{deaths in past 10 minutes}} {\text{target deaths per 10 minutes}} + \text{max} \left( 0, 1 - 2 \frac {\text{current oxygen amount}} {\text{standard oxygen tank size}} \right)^2 + \frac {\text{minutes in low oxygen warning}} {\text{target minutes in warning}}$$
Then you can define ranges of stress values where you want to use more generous vs. more challenging generation rules. Or you can directly use a function of stress to vary things like oxygen bottle / hazard spawn rates continuously. Just make sure to impose caps on the formula so it doesn't return values outside of what you'd deem a sensible range.
The exact tuning of this is something only someone with direct access to your game can do well, but hopefully the above gives you some starting points for a general approach that can help.
Lastly, some risks to watch out for when implementing dynamic difficulty:

Player perception: players like to believe they're overcoming challenges through their own skill, so a prideful player might feel insulted or condescended-to if the game lowers the bar to make it easier for them. Conversely, a player who does well may feel like the game is cheating or punishing them if their success is rewarded by making the game harder.

Gaming the system: if players know the game adjusts its difficulty parameters in response to their play, this can create a perverse incentive to deliberately play badly to drop the challenge at a critical juncture.

The Red Queen effect: if the game always gets harder to match the player's skill and effort, then as they improve, an overly-responsive system can deny them tangible benefits from that improvement. Despite playing better, they're still progressing just as slowly or dying just as often, because the increased difficulty exactly countered their efforts. Just like the Red Queen in Lewis Carrol's Through the Looking Glass, the player is running as fast as they can just to stay in the same place. This can be demotivating.
You can ameliorate this by adding latency, so the player gets a grace period to reap the rewards of their improved skills before the difficulty rises to match. Or, you can tune the steepness of your difficulty ramp to counter less than 100% of the player's increased success — so they see diminishing returns from getting better, but not zero returns.



Indeed there are various problems with adjusting the difficulty dynamically during the game. This is why I focus on determining the difficulty only once, at the beginning of the game. I would like to have a 'tuning phase' of about 30 seconds, then determine the relevant parameters, then start the game with these parameters fixed. My question is: how can I determine the formula for the "stress" level?

Unfortunately, that part is likely to involve trial and error. Pick a starting point like the example I gave above, and play through multiple game scenarios (or recruit playtesters and observe them playing through multiple scenarios). If the stress values you get are too high/low for your experience goals, change the coefficients and try again.
